# Django passing variables using request

Tags: django-views

Im trying to pass a variables from html file and trying to access it in my view..But I get this error..--signup_vol_position exactly takes 2 arguments ( 1 given)

views.py

```
def signup_vol_position(request,comments):
        pdb.set_trace()
        if request.method == 'POST':
                print('if')
        else:
                print('else')
        teamrel = VolunteerRequirement.objects.values_list('teamrelation',flat=T
        vollist = VolunteerRequirement.objects.order_by('teamrelation')
        variable = RequestContext(request, {'vollist': vollist,'teamrel':teamrel
        return render_to_response('signups/volunteer_list.dmpl',variable)
        #variable = RequestContext(request,{'comments':comments}
        #return render_to_response('sfp.view',variable)
```

html file

```
<table>

{% for v in vollist %}
{% ifchanged  v.teamrelation %}
<tr>
<th colspan=7 align="left"><h3><a name="{{ v.teamrelation }}"> {{v.teamrelation}} </a> </h3></th>
</tr>
{% endifchanged %}


<tr>
        <th colspan=4 align="left"><label for="id_Volposition">Volunteer Position:</label></th>
        <th colspan=.5 align="left"><a href="/signups/volposition/{{ v.position }}" class="username" <u>{{ v.volposition }}</u></a></th>
<tr> <td colspan="2" height="2" style="display:none">&nbsp;</td> </tr>
</tr>
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
   (r'^new/$',                           sfp.view),
   (r'^volunteer/$',     volunteer_page),
   (r'^vollist/$', volunteer_list),
   (r'^volcont/$', volunteer_contact),
   (r'^volposition/$',signup_vol_position)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

The function signup_vol_position requires one more argument apart from the request object, as per your definition. However, in urls.py you have not accounted for that argument. Should have been something like

```
(r'^volposition/(.+)$',signup_vol_position)
```

See if that works.